# How to use the 'in' attribute of grid in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

In Tkinter using grid geometry manager, how can I put Other widgets inside of a Frame? I know there is a 'in' attribute of grid, but I Am not sure about the correct syntax

I have used master=frame in the widget but still, by row and column it is coming in the root and not in the frame (I know it's because I have not used the 'in' attribute of grid)

If I just do grid(row=0,column=0,in=frame) Then an error comes, so how exactly should I use the 'in' attribute of grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Tkinter using grid geometry manager, how can I put Other widgets inside of a Frame?

The normal way is to make the widget a child of a frame.

```
frame = tk.Frame(...)
other_widget = tk.Label(frame, ...)
```

> I know there is a 'in' attribute of grid, but I Am not sure about the correct syntax

The correct syntax is to set the attribute `in_` to some other widget. We have to use `in_` rather than `in` because `in` is a reserved word in Python.

Further, there are restrictions for which widgets can be a target of `in_`. From the canonical documentation:

> The container for each content must either be the content's parent (the default) or a descendant of the content's parent. This restriction is necessary to guarantee that the content can be placed over any part of its container that is visible without danger of the content being clipped by its parent.

> I have used master=frame in the widget but still, by row and column it is coming in the root

If that is the case, `frame` is most likely set to `None`. That will happen if you create `frame` and call `pack` or `grid` all in a single statement (eg: `frame = tk.Frame(root).pack()`). This is a very common mistake.

The reason that `frame` is `None` is due to how python handles function results.  If you do `x = y().z()`, `x` will be set to the result of `.z()`. Since `pack`, `place`, and `grid` all return `None`, if you do `frame = tk.Frame(...).grid(...)`, `frame` will be `None`.

Here's an example of how to use `in_`, though it's far more common to make the widgets a child of the frame instead of using `in_`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")

frame1 = tk.Frame(root, background="bisque")
frame1.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)

# create a label as a child of the root window
label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello, world")

# add the label to the frame. 
label.grid(in_=frame1, row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: for the 'frame1' you used the 'pack' in a separate line, but if you use 'pack' in the same line like

frame1 = tk.Frame(root, background="bisque").pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)

Then why does it not work

Comment: @Krehan_Shah: because `x = y().z()` sets `x` to the value of `z()`. Thus, `frame1 = tk.Frame(...).pack(...)` returns the value of `pack(...)`, and `pack(...)` returns `None`. Thus, `frame1` will be set to `None`.